# How can I check if Table B matches quantity of items that exists in Table A? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, table A and Table B, and I want to check if Table B matches quantity of items that exists on Table A, so, for example:

**Table A**

| S_O | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITA | 1 |
| 3 | ITB | 2 |
| 4 | ITC | 3 |
| 6 | ITD | 0 |

**Table B**

| S_O | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITA | 1 |
| 3 | ITB | 2 |
| 4 | ITC | 3 |
| 6 | ITD | 5 |
| 7 | ITE | 2 |
| 8 | ITF | 1 |

My first thought was to use an except between the two tables, but then I was asked to check if the quantity was OK or if it was shortage to generate a preview like:

***Result from comparing the two tables***

| S_O | ITEM | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITA | OK |
| 3 | ITB | OK |
| 4 | ITC | OK |
| 6 | ITD | SHORTAGE |

And it needs to ignore items "ITE" and "ITF" because they don't exist in Table A
I'm pretty new with sql server queries, I think I could use a SELECT CASE but I don't know how to do it, I'd appreciate some help in this matter
In those tables my unique identifier is S_O, so it would need to match the S_O, item and quantity for both tables

Comment: Is `Item` unique in the table? If so you just need to join on item and subtract the `QTY`'s

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, I can have multiple rows with the same Items, my unique identifier is S_O

Comment: This is pretty important info - you should add it to the question. Anyway you need to pre-aggregate both tables so it is unique, then join on this column. So if there are two records for ITA with QTY 3 and 5, you want to aggregate to one record with a value of 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can "pre summarise" table a and b to make item unique, then join:

```
select 
  A.item, 
  A.qty as qtya, 
  B.qty as qtyb, 
  A.qty - B.qty as shortageamt,
  case 
    when A.qty = B.qty then 'OK' 
    else 'Shortage' 
  end as status
from
(
  select item, sum(qty) as qty
  from tablea
  group by item
) as A
inner join
(
  select item, sum(qty) as qty
  from tableb
  group by item
) as B
on A.item = B.item
```

You'll *only* get an item listed in the result if it's in both tables - is that what you want? if ITG is in tablea but not tableb, do you want to see it (with qty 0)? That requires an outer join.

Comment: This works perfect, I don't really need to see ITG if it doesn't exist in table B, so it's okay. Thank you for your help! I'm really glad of it

Comment: I would modify the case so that if a.QTY is < b.QTY it doesn't say shortage... "overage" maybe?  Otherwise those results will be misleading.

Comment: I mean a.QTY is > b.QTY

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with a `LEFT JOIN`. Also, the first answer does not `JOIN` on S_O, which you state in your question you need.
*"In those tables my unique identifier is S_O, so it would need to match the S_O, item and quantity for both tables"*

```
DECLARE @ta TABLE (S_O INT, ITEM VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
INSERT INTO @ta
VALUES
(1, 'ITA',  1),
(3, 'ITB',  2),
(4, 'ITC',  3),
(6, 'ITD',  0)


DECLARE @tb TABLE (S_O INT, ITEM VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
INSERT INTO @tb
VALUES
(1, 'ITA',  1),
(3, 'ITB',  2),
(4, 'ITC',  3),
(6, 'ITD',  5),
(7, 'ITE',  2),
(8, 'ITF',  1);

SELECT ta.S_O,
    ta.ITEM,
    CASE WHEN ta.ITEM = tb.ITEM AND SUM(ta.QTY) >= SUM(tb.QTY) THEN 'OK' ELSE 'SHORTAGE' END AS 'STATUS'
FROM @ta ta
    LEFT JOIN @tb tb ON ta.S_O = tb.S_O
GROUP BY ta.S_O, ta.ITEM, tb.ITEM
```

| S_O | ITEM | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITA | OK |
| 3 | ITB | OK |
| 4 | ITC | OK |
| 6 | ITD | SHORTAGE |

Comment: "I can have multiple rows with the same Items". Meaning if you join on S_O, you'll get multiple rows with the same item. For example if there are two ITA records in one table, you'll end up with duplicates and double counting. The original question and example does not state this, but the subsequent clarification does.

Comment: I believe my quote from the question was an edit in response to your comment. A better MRE would've helped in this case, as I can see a situation with multiple rows assigned to different S_O's being expected and required to be handled independently even with the same item.

Comment: I agree -  a better MRE is required here. There are a lot of cases not covered in the original question, therefore requiring assumptions.